# I downloaded the Coco2d-x game from the link on the downloads page of www.coco2d-x.org. now, how to get it working?

Tags: visual-c++, cocos2d-x, marmalade

From this link [Cocos2D_Game](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/attachments/535/Cocos2dxSimpleGame-0.9.1.rar) I downloaded the game and extracted the files.

Visual c++ express 2010 and marmalaid 5.2.1(from marmalaid.com) is installed (of-course on windows 7).

Now, which file is to be used to run the game. I tried almost all expected files. and when I press run, it returns an error "unable to start program... blah blah blah"

is there any special file to run the project ?

I didn't found *.mkb file in that project.

Please help me setting up this Cocos2d-x setup on my system for the first time.

And yeah, i just recalled on more thing.
I downloaded Cocos2d-x on my system. Extracted it. and kept it in my "d: drive".

Where shall the extract of Cocos2d-x be kept? Do I need specific path for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't shake the feeling that you haven't read any of the [cocos2d-x documentation](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/4/wiki), in particular the [Visual Studio user's guide](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Cocos2d-x_Application_Wizard_for_Visual_Studio_User_Guide). That's where you should start.

Comment: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki i got it... "SO" is not letting me to post my answer myself. i can post only after 2 hours. :)

Comment: and the game downloaded is still missing png files. so, its returning an error. i added a few png myself...  but, didn't got the game !